# How do you auto-duplex on HP m277dw printer with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, laser-printer, duplex

Various forums suggest [setting](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Auto-duplexing-on-the-HP-Color-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M277dw/td-p/5023533) the **Duplex Unit** to *Installed* on the **Device Settings** dialog to get the HP m277dw printer to print double sided. I have done this and it works if I *manually* flip the pages:

[image]

This model printer has allowed for automatic duplexing for versions of Windows prior to Windows 10.

What can I do to cause the printer to *auto*-duplex under Windows 10, whether that's a setting on the printer itself, a driver update, or some obscure Windows setting? HP Support [doesn't seem to know what to do](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/MFP-M277-dw-win-10/td-p/5241771).

Comment: There are 2 models: the M277N and the M277DW. The "N" does not have a duplexer (hardware) installed. Check to make sure you have indeed the "DW"

Comment: I do have the *dw*.

Comment: Try reinstalling the driver. First delete the printer. Then click on any other printer and on "Print Server Properties", the Drivers tab and remove the printer from the list. Then reinstall from the CD. Don't let Win-10 install its own driver.

Comment: My answer just got an upvote, so it must have worked for someone besides just me. It didn't require reinstalling the driver, and I, too, already knew that my printer could do double sided. I just needed to change a printer property, and now I can go back and forth between double and single sided like I expected.

Comment: @Sigfried thanks for your answer. That worked like a charm! Crazy how it took years. It looks like I tried that in 2016, but it didn't work. I tried it just now to verify your answer, and it did! I guess all the drivers and OS caught up to the point it actually works.

Comment: Glad it helped. Yeah, when I looked back at your question, it seemed like you must have followed the same steps. The problem popped up for me months ago. I forget what had changed, but it had been working earlier, so I knew it could. ... And nice chain of events: some mysterious third person upvotes my answer; in my greed for reputation I nag you with a comment on the original post; you return after years of hopeless resignation; it works; you select my answer; I ascend to 146 reputation points; everyone's happy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me what worked is this series of steps:

- open settings
- choose printers and scanners
- click the printer (M277dw)
- manage
- printer properties
- device settings
- for Duplex Unit, choose Installed

Comment: Thanks! I was really puzzled as to why the duplexer worked fine on my dual boot windows/linux machine in linux but not windows!